# How can i make a license for an application developed in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorporating license key approach for a WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447715/incorporating-license-key-approach-for-a-winforms-app)

I would like to make random license key such that if any one installed my application i would like to give him a license along with the application which may end in a month or so. And the key should only work on particular system he installed and not in any other PC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447715/incorporating-license-key-approach-for-a-winforms-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many commercial products that might help you in this task. One example is [xheo](http://xheo.com/).

Comment: If i wish to develop my own license then how can i do this for complete application

Comment: I would recommend you not developing custom solutions but use one of the existing licencing libraries out there. Remember that cracking a licence is directly proportional to time and pirate skills, so if you really value your intellectual property don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question:

[Securing a license key with RSA key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548426/securing-a-license-key-with-rsa-key/2548542#2548542)